# Why does .count() break Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor

Here is my `routes.js`

```
Router.route('/database_setup', function () {

    //Subscribe and stuff
    Downloads = new Mongo.Collection('downloads');
    Meteor.subscribe('downloads');

    var downloads = {
        movies :  Downloads.find({type : 'movies'})
    };

    if (downloads.movies.count() > 0) { // BREAKS HERE 

    }

    this.render('database_setup');
});
```

If I remove the place I've marked, everything works fine. Otherwise, I get the following error:

[image]

Weird thing is, calling `downloads.movies.count()` in the console works fine.

What's going on here?

Comment: Do you have another file with `new Mongo.Collection('downloads');` in it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Downloads = new Mongo.Collection('downloads');` should be somewhere where it will only be called once. You create the new Mongo Collection once and subscribe to it many times.

Standard practice is to have a `/lib` folder where you organize your collections.

Comment: It might work the first time you load the app.

Never define a new collection inside routes.

The new collection should be outside the route declaration. Else, it will be called every time that route is called (which is why you get this error)

Comment: Right! Old habits die hard. Thanks :)